# How to loop trough map and get record by field value

Tags: apex, map, loop, record, get

I have a `map<Id,String> subMap` this is the id of a record where the string is a name of a Future_record__c yet to be made after a callout.

How do I loop through the subMap and get the Future_record__c by the value of the String. Do I need to do a subloop or something?

I have the following currently:

```
List<Future_record__c> subList = [select id, Name, LastModifiedDate from Future_record__c where Name IN :stringNames];
        for (Id key : subMap.keySet()) {
              if (SubList.get(SubMap.value????).LastModifiedDate > ModifiedAfter) {
               //Do something 
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the String value in submap to identify future_record__c records in subList, matching on name?

Change subList into a Map where the name is the key -

```
List<Future_record__c> subList = [select id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
                                 FROM Future_record__c where Name IN :stringNames];
Map<String, future_record__c> futureRecordNameMap = new Map<String, future_record__c>();
for(future_record__c futureRecord :subList){
     futureRecordNameMap.put(futureRecord.name, futureRecord);
}
```

Then loop through the values of submap, rather than the keys, to match the records you want:

```
   for (String futureRecordName : subMap.values()) {
      if (futureRecordNameMap.get(futureRecordName).LastModifiedDate > ModifiedAfter) {
               //Do something 
      }
   }
```

OR, if you need the key from the subMap for something, loop through the keys and just get the value from submap -

```
for (Id subMapKey: subMap.keySet()) {
      if (futureRecordNameMap.get(subMap.get(subMapKey)).LastModifiedDate > ModifiedAfter) {
               //Do something 
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic Apex, the **[get](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)** method on your object for this type of access.

```
Map<ID, Future_record__c> m = new Map<ID, Future_record__c>([select id, Name, LastModifiedDate from Future_record__c where Name IN :stringNames]);

for (Id key : subMap.keySet()) {
    if (m.containsKey(key)){
        Future_record__c fr = m.get(key);
        //If your field is of type String, you would cast it as below 
        String value = (String)fr.get(subMap.get(key));
        //Do something with the value
    }
}
```

Comment: @Saroybera In my case map<Id,String> id is a childrecord of Stringvalue record

Comment: @Thomas Could you please add some more details. I am still not clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Saroybera Map<ID, Future_record__c>. Id is the Id of a different object. Obj a= new Obj (Namefuturerecord='tobemade'). if (SubList.get('tobemade' ????).LastModifiedDate > ModifiedAfter)